# Please, please help me install Ubuntu as a UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10, error-handling

I have been working at this for easily 15 hours now and nothing works. First I had linux installed and I wanted to install windows as a dual boot, which took 8 hours because of all the issues. It finally worked but I had windows as UEFI and Linux as Legacy. So I followed multiple websites on how to convert linux to UEFI and nothing worked so I thought, hey maybe I'll reformat all the drives that I have Linux on and just do a fresh restart. Well in order to create a UEFI boot loader I have to switch legacy mode off in my bios. However anytime I try to run my USB drive with Ubuntu loaded in UEFI mode, I get multiple errors saying,

ACPI BIOS error (bug) Faliure creating named object[_SB.PCI0.XC.RHUB.8809._UPC], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (2019086/psob.ject-220)

Over and over again along with weird colored lines streaking all across the black background and it just sits there. I tried loading it up many times, I made multiple ISO. files on multiple flash drives with different tools and trying GPT, FAT32 etc and nothing works. Now I have no linux and a slow working windows 10 on my HDD and my SSD is empty waiting for linux to get reinstalled. Please help! I don't care what I have to delete I just want this working. Thank you!

Comment: What version Ubuntu are you trying to install, and on what machine?  Others have had similar problems (search this site and the forums). Is your BIOS/firmware up to date?

Comment: Actually I just solved it, ironically after I asked. So I had to use install ubuntu using the no graphics option and it finally installed. Everything works now both are running on the UEFI. I only wish I installed windows on my SSD also because it runs so slow on the HDD. Anyhow I am thankful it works.  Thank you.

Comment: You may post your own answer to this, then accept it after a waiting period so others may benefit from your solution.

Comment: Just for reference. Best to not turn Legacy/BIOS/CSM on. Often have to update UEFI and if SSD, the SSD firmware. Drives often have to be changed from Intel RST to AHCI. Sometimes other UEFI setting. And Windows fast start up has to be off. Shows live installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Also shows Windows 10 screens or similar to Windows 8
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: Yeah when I first installed Linux along with Windows I was unaware it was installing in Legacy mode and my Windows was UEFI, I didn't even know they existed. Then I deleted Windows to run pure Linux, which was Legacy. So trying to reinstall Windows was a nightmare but having UEFI windows and Linux Legacy made issues so using the run ubuntu in safe mode is what finally got me through the issue. I think the problem is also that I have a nvidia driver which causes issues with the splash screen and the gui, so maybe that is why running it in safe mode allowed me to access and see the screen?